# How to use macropackage in LaTex?

Tags: macros, packages

I have used LaTex amspackage to type a math article. The publisher is asking me to do it in Springer LaTex macropackage with the option of 'smallextended.'
I have no idea how to do this. Help please!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I don't understand why people are voting to close this as it is very clear what the OP is asking. True, they haven't provided a MWE but the OP is new to TeX.SX and probably to TeX and there's not much that a MWE can do here. Shouldn't we try to be more inclusive?

Comment: @Andrew yes. That's why I answered.

Answer (score 6):

They mean something like

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}
```

but with `smallextended` in the options between `[]` and perhaps a different class than `svmono` depending on your requirements.

Springer have extensive documentation and examples in a zip file you can download from

http://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/book-authors-editors/book-manuscript-guidelines/manuscript-preparation/5636